# Spring MVC Tests MockMvc methods

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, mocking

I have a method in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public final String mainGet(final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap model)
        throws ServletException {

    model.addAttribute("fontSize", fontSize);
    courses = persistenceServices.getCourses();
    model.addAttribute("coursesList", courses);

    return "home";
}
```

I wrote a simple test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:tests.xml" })
@WebAppConfiguration
public class TestHomeController {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private PersistenceServices persistenceServicesMock;

    @InjectMocks
    private HomeController homeController;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(homeController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testMainGet() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform( get("/")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(view().name("home"));

        verify(persistenceServicesMock, times(1));
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(persistenceServicesMock);
    }
```

Everything seems well, but I cannot call any MvcMock's method. Eclipse underlines all of them (perform, status, view etc.) and shows me information:

```
The method perform(RequestBuilder) in the type MockMvc is not applicable for the arguments (MockHttpServletRequestBuilder)
```

I tried to cast arguments to RequestBuilder and ResultMatcher, but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you static importing get, status, view and etc?

Comment: Yes, I have something like that:                                 import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;

Comment: Remove the wac declaration. Since you're using a Standalone setup, you don't need it.
Also, MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); should be called after the mockMVCbuilder.

Comment: Okey, I removed wac. When I call MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) after the mockMVCbuilder, I have NullPointerException. If I have MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) before mockMVCbuilder I have error: MockHttpServletRequestBuilder cannot be cast to RequestBuilder.

Comment: NullPointer is because you haven't initialized your controller. Declare as: private HomeController homeController = new HomeController();

Answer (score 1):

try to put

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
```